# Svelte Each function in Nested Json

Tags: svelte

I have nested JSON Array

```
let car = [
{
    name: "BMW",
    detail: [
        {name: headlight, type: flame},
        {name: taillight, type: spark},
    ],
},
{
    name: "Merced Benz",
    detail: [
        {name: headlight, type: spark},
        {name: taillight, type: flame},
    ],
},]
```

it's show cars name when i call
`{#each car as cars}`
`<p>{cars.name}</p>`
`{/each}`

but 
when i call `{cars.detail}` its show `[object Object]` 
and
when i call `{cars.detail.name}` its show `Undefined`

i wanna call each name of detail

please help me to use this each function at svelte thank you before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `detail` is an array, you have to use another each block to iterate over that as well.

**Example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1aa5ccfb164b44b7969479b56190b569?version=3.5.1))**

```html
<script>
  let cars = [
    {
      name: "BMW",
      detail: [
        { name: "headlight", type: "flame" },
        { name: "taillight", type: "spark" }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Mercedes-Benz",
      detail: [
        { name: "headlight", type: "spark" },
        { name: "taillight", type: "flame" }
      ]
    }
  ];
</script>

{#each cars as car}
  <div>{car.name}</div>
  {#each car.detail as detail}
    <div>{detail.name}: {detail.type}</div>
  {/each}
{/each}
```